# Difficulties on defining rules for read actions on Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter, firebase-security

I have the following collection structure on firestore:

```
> collection > {document1}  > subcollection > {document2}
document1 has the following fields:
- alias
- serial
- userID ("from request.auth.uid")

document2 has the following fields:
- date
- code
```

I was able to create rules that restricts the write actions, the set of rules below works just fine for `create` and `update`.

However, when it comes to read actions it doesn't work as I think it would:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function signedIn() {
      return request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    function verifiedUserSignedIn() {
        return request.auth.token.email_verified;
    }

    match /collection/{document1} {
        function ownUser_onWrites() {
        return request.resource.data.userID == request.auth.uid;
      }
        function ownUser_onReads() {
        return resource.data.userID == request.auth.uid;
      }

      allow create: if verifiedUserSignedIn();
      // Permissive update
      // TODO: must allow update only on specific fields
      allow update: if verifiedUserSignedIn() && ownUser_onWrites();
      allow read: if verifiedUserSignedIn() && ownUser_onReads();

      match /subcollection/{document2} {

        allow create: if verifiedUserSignedIn() && ownUser_onWrites();
        // Permissive update
        // TODO: must allow update only on specific fields
        allow update: if verifiedUserSignedIn() && ownUser_onWrites();
        allow read: if verifiedUserSignedIn() && ownUser_onReads();

      }
    }

// Permissive access (to be replaced)
//      match /collection/{document1=**} {
//          allow read, write: if verifiedUserSignedIn();
//      }
    match /anothercollection/{anotherdocument=**} {
        allow read, write: if verifiedUserSignedIn();
    }

  }
}
```

It doesn't work even on the simulator with `list` and `get` operations (`create` and `update` works). On the simulator I try to access the location `/collection/{document1}` and I get `"Simulated data access denied"`.

On flutter I use a StreamBuilder and query the collection for match the own user userID:

```
...
final CollectionReference collectionReference = Firestore.instance.collection("collection");
...
      body: new StreamBuilder(
        stream: collectionReference.where('userID', isEqualTo: _userId).snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData)
            return const Text('Nothing to show');
          return new GridView.builder(
            gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              childAspectRatio: 8.0 / 8.0,
            ),
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                widget._buildListFromCollection(context, snapshot, index, _userId),
          );
        },
      ),
...
```

Just to be clear, the code works perfectly when I remove the `ownUser_onReads()` from the read rule of the `/collection/{document1}` match:

`allow read: if verifiedUserSignedIn();// && ownUser_onReads(); <-- removed condition`

Anyone?

Comment: Might be related with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691228/using-resource-data-in-firestore-rules/51343997#51343997)

Comment: Please update your question to include the code for the read operation that you can't get to work.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen done.

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't immediately see what's wrong with these rules. Hopefully somebody else spots the problem.